# Integrate $\int\arccos(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}})dx$

Tags: integration, integral-domain

I need integrate:
$$\int\arccos(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}})dx$$

How can i solve it? is it good way substitute argument of arccos? $$t=\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}$$

Comment: Did you try that substitution? I would go a slightly different way, but I would appreciate if you at least showed us what you got from that substitution. If it was successful or not.

Comment: i tried it and i get this

$$dx=\frac{20t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$

Comment: I think it should be $dx=\frac{20t}{(t^2-1)^2}\,dt$, right? Anyways, I posted the other route as an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another route:

First integrating by parts, writing the integral as
$$
\int 1\cdot \arccos\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\,dx
$$
will leave you with an integral like (I forget about constants, and suggest you to do the calculations!)
$$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x-4}(x+6)}\,dx.
$$
Adding and subtracting $6$ in the numerator (and integrating the part looking like $1/\sqrt{x-4}$) will leave you with something like
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-4}(x+6)}\,dx
$$
Now, let $t=\sqrt{x-4}$ and you will get something like (again, check constants)
$$
\int\frac{1}{t^2+10}\,dt,
$$
which will just give an arctan.

If you want to know what I actually got in the end, move your mouse over the box below.

> $$ x \arccos\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}+\sqrt{10(x-4)}-6\arctan\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{10}}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Here is a route.

By the change of variable 
$$
t=\sqrt{\dfrac{x-4}{x+6}}\qquad x= 2\:\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{1-t^2} \qquad dx= 2\left(\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{1-t^2}\right)'dt
$$ one may obtain
$$
\int\arccos(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}})\:dx=2\int\left(\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{1-t^2}\right)'\arccos(t)\:dt
$$ then one may integrate by parts to get
$$
\int\arccos(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}})\:dx=2\left(\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{1-t^2}\right)\arccos(t)+2\int\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\:dt
$$ The latter integral may be evaluated by the change of variable $t:=\sin u$ yielding
$$
\int\dfrac{ 3 t^2+2}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\:dt=\frac{10 t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-6\: \text{arcsin}(t)+C, \quad |t|<1.
$$